# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices not in GAC

Tags: ssis

I have a few SSIS packages that i want to execute programmatically using a windows application.
I found a few examples that i want to follow.  To  do so, I need to set a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.  i cannot find it in the GAC
I have SQL Server 2012 developer edition installed on my machine.
Also looked on the SQL server running Enterprise edition.  this dll is not there either.

What am i missing?  Thanks in advance for your help

Habib

Comment: That DLL would be installed if they had select the Integration Services Service as part of the SQL Server installation. Can you confirm/deny as to whether that was done?